# How can I do integration with the Green theorem?

Tags: numerical-integration, vector-calculus

I have an integral
$$\int_C xy^2dx-4x\sin y\,dy$$
where $C$ bounded with some constrains, for instance inside $x^2+y^2=1$ and below $y=x^2$.

I can integrate of one variable and also with some calculations do above integral, but I want to know how can Mathematica do it. Is it something of the form

```
Integrate[f[x]-g[y], {x, 0, 2 π}, {y, 0, 2 π}]
```

but it doesn't work, or can software do that!

How can I do this type of integrals? Thanks.

Comment: I would rewrite it in polar coordinates...

Comment: Thanks. but I want just this form!

Comment: From the documentation of `Integrate`, you can specify a region. Example from the doc: `Integrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] Sphere[]]`.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is triple integral but the question is about some weird with $x$ and $y$ variable!

Comment: Integrate[x y^2 - 4 x Sin[y], {x, y}  \[Element] Circle[]]... "..weird x and y.." gives you a circle...

Comment: This makes sense I think

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use Green's theorem to turn the line integral into an area integral?

Comment: @CarlWoll I'm able to calculate mathematically this form of problems with many ways, but I like to Mathematica do it with this form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Green's theorem is simplest. Here is `L`, `M` and the `region`:

```
L[x_, y_] := x y^2
M[x_, y_] := -4 x Sin[y]
region = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 < 1 && y < x^2, {x, y}];
```

Visualize `region`:

```
Region @ region
```

[image]

Perform integral:

```
    NIntegrate[D[M[x, y], x] - D[L[x, y], y], {x, y} ∈ region]
```

> 2.09163

Answers using the line integral approach can be compared to this answer.

**Update for M9 users**

In M9, one can use [`Boole`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole):

```
NIntegrate[
    (D[M[x, y], x]-D[L[x, y], y]) Boole[x^2+y^2<1 && y<x^2],
    {x,-1,1},
    {y,-1,1}
]
```

> 2.09163

Comment: Thanks. I restart my software but it doesn't work (version 9.0). Is it need to execute a package (like ancient versions) for your codes?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the code line gets screwed up in comments...

```
Integrate[x y^2 - 4 x Sin[y], {x, y} \[Element] Circle[]]
```

with zero output.

Reference is [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html) ,and [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Circle.html) for how to define the unit circle...

Another way to express it is

```
Integrate[x y^2 - 4 x Sin[y], {x, y} \[Element] Circle[{0, 0}, 1]]
```

Comment: How do I add the condition $y\geq x^2$.?

Comment: condition is there. See edits, pls.